# Putting list of AngularJs scripts out of HTML codes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, htmlcleaner

I have a long list of controllers, services, factories, directives,etc files and I dont want to use this long list of `<script>` inside the ***head*** or ***body*** of the HTML. 
Is there anyway to put them somewhere, that my codes look more clean?

Comment: external javascript ?

Comment: linking them in the html let's them preload as soon as the </body> hits, which is ideal from a performance perspective, second to concat'ing them into one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inline scripts, put all code in external js file and use that.

If you are including lot of js files(even though its just fine to do so), use a build tool like **Grunt** to concatenate all the js files if you dont want too many of them. They will put all the code in one js file which you can include at the end.

Comment: putting all of script files in one file and including them at the end of body seems more doable at the moment for me.
Grunt or Gulp takes time to learn ...
Thanks

Comment: Yup, agreed. But, when the projects starts to scale, its good to have automated builds.. Plus learn grunt as per your needs, no need for mastery. Basics and using plugins, you can learn in 2,3 hours.

Comment: There are always docs to get you going, grunt is build on node, so it needs to be installed first. You dont need to know much about node, just basic npm commands for installing grunt. Anyways one of the tutorials, I found nice is https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-simple-guide-to-getting-started-with-grunt  . Otherwise, google is always there to get you going..